# How to check when a date is not filled in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to apply a function that is based on a condition where a date is filled or not.

The date is stored as an object: `date object`.

It looks like this in the dataframe when it's not filled: `date NaT`.

If I write a function that looks like this `if pd.to_datetime(data['date']) == None` or `if pd.to_datetime(data['date']) == pd.NaT` it's not working.

How could I verify this condition ?

Comment: please provide sample input data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the date is empty using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329516/how-to-check-the-date-is-empty-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isnull`

```py
>>> df
        Year  Week_No  Value
0 2015-01-01       52      3
1 2016-01-01        2      7
2        NaT       51      5
3 2016-01-01        1      6
4 2015-01-01       50      4
>>>
>>>
>>> df.Year.isnull()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: Year, dtype: bool
```